# How can I get a result of select all in snowflake javascript procedure into another temporary table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a JavaScript procedure which getting rows from a table. The script looks like that:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id<1000";
var stmt = snowflake.createSnowflake({sqlText: sql});
var rs = stmt.execute();
rs.next();
```

I need to take the `rs` and copy it into another table, but I am not able to do it as when I return `rs` I can only see one record.

Can I loop over the fetched data to the inserts like:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    // insert into ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about looping:
According to docs a ResultSet is similar to a SQL cursor, i.e. you can see one row at a time in a ResultSet. Typically, after you retrieve a ResultSet, you iterate through it by using next().

Here you can find an example for using next() and retrieving the result values: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html

Regarding your overall task, you mention that you "need to take the rs and copy it into another table". Probably using `INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM sourceTable` is solving your problem without having to loop the resultset. Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html